# Entity framework with oracle views

Tags: oracle, entity-framework

I have a problem using Entity Framework with oracle views, or views in general. I can easily retrieve data from the views through my Entity, which has views only and no tables, but I can't insert, update, or delete any records. This gives the below error below:

```
The table/view does not have a primary key defined. The Entity is read-only
```

This occurs even though all my views have at least one Field having "Entity Key" checked.

Note:
I am using VS2013 and EF 6

Comment: I'm having the same problem and I've spent days with this. I still haven't found the solution. Have you? If you have please share

Answer (score 2):

Your view needs to be **updateable** (no joins possible) and must have definded **primary key** (for entity framework, constraint can be disabled, like shown below).

Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MYVIEW ( 

ID, 
<COLUMNS>,

CONSTRAINT UNIQUENAMEFORPKCONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (<PK_COLUMN>) DISABLE ) 

AS
SELECT <COLUMNS> FROM <TABLE> WHERE <CONDITIONS>;
```